# kivy выход текста за пределы экрана

Tags: python, kivy

При установки программы на телефоны с разным разрешение экрана размер текста (Label) меняется из-за этого может выйти  за пределы экрана. Можно ли адаптировать текст под разные разрешения чтобы текст не выходил из-за экрана.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Установите размер рамки, которая ограничивает текст:

```
"""
By default, the label is not constrained to any bounding box.
You can set the  size constraint of the label with this property.
The text will autoflow into the constraints. So although the font size will not be reduced,
the text will be arranged to fit into the box as best as possible,
with any text still outside the box clipped.

This sets and clips texture_size to text_size if not None.

For example, whatever your current widget size is,
if you want the label to be created in a box with width=200 and unlimited height:
"""

Label(text='Very big big line', text_size=(200, None))
```

Или в kv разметке:

```
#: import Window kivy.core.window.Window


Label:
    # Рамка, где текст будет вписан с отступом в 15 dp от левого и правого краев экрана.
    text_size: Window.width - dp(15), None
```